# Создал бота для Discord на python работал нормально но вдруг перестал(код не менял, он просто так перестал работать)

Tags: python, бот, discord

Вот ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/one/DiscordBot.py", line 2012, in <module>
    Bot.run("тут рабочий токен")
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\one\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 640, in run
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\one\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 621, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\one\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 585, in start
    await self.connect(reconnect=reconnect)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\one\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 499, in connect
    await self._connect()
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\one\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 463, in _connect
    await self.ws.poll_event()
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\one\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\gateway.py", line 471, in poll_event
    await self.received_message(msg)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\one\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\gateway.py", line 425, in received_message
    func(data)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\one\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\state.py", line 750, in parse_guild_create
    guild = self._get_create_guild(data)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\one\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\state.py", line 725, in _get_create_guild
    guild._from_data(data)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\one\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\guild.py", line 297, in _from_data
    self._sync(guild)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\one\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\guild.py", line 328, in _sync
    self._add_channel(CategoryChannel(guild=self, data=c, state=self._state))
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\one\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\channel.py", line 726, in __init__
    self._update(guild, data)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\one\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\channel.py", line 737, in _update
    self._fill_overwrites(data)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\one\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\abc.py", line 294, in _fill_overwrites
    self._overwrites.append(_Overwrites(id=overridden_id, **overridden))
TypeError: __new__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'deny_new'
```

Answer (score 0):

Просто переустановите последнюю версию Discord.py

```
python3 -m pip install -U discord.py
```

Вот и все.